# How to use the AlchemyAPI for face detection / recognition in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, alchemy, alchemyapi

This is pretty much a generic question and just would like someone to point me the right direction. I understand the existence of an API in Alchemy as documented in :http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/image-tagging/urls.html?__hstc=27013730.9b40428638d250ef6490e695d551207d.1458459083806.1458459083806.1458459083806.1&__hssc=27013730.1.1458459083807&__hsfp=2749035364

I have managed to call the API but unable to make any sense out of the data. My code thus far is as below :

```
import requests

apikey = "01405e7492ca333c6ab3a5c7da544e9f11bf6e26"
picture = open('IMG_1172.JPG','rb').read()
url="http://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/image/ImageGetRankedImageKeywords?apikey=01405e7492ca333c6ab3a5c7da544e9f11bf6e26&outputMode=json&forceShowAll=1"
r = requests.post(url = url, data = picture)
print r.txt
```

The above r.txt was unable to be executed as it shows Response 200. I was suppose to receive a json file back from my API call but I don't see it here.

Appreciate if anyone could guide me on this. Thanks !